# Are these two Sklearn.ensemble methods working with regressors?

Tags: python, regression, linear-gradients

How does [`GradientBoostingRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor) and [`RandomForestRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) work? Are these Multiple Linear Regression methods with Decision Trees?

I do not really understand how these methods works from the [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble), can someone help me?

Comment: do you have some code you are working on?  have you gone through examples? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html